# Angular AOT compilation fails with npm package

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular2-aot, angular-aot

I am a complete newbee to web development, and now I am facing a problem that I do not know how to deal with.

I am using the npm package named @uniprank/ngx-file-uploader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@uniprank/ngx-file-uploader) in my web application, which is developed in Typescript with Angular 4. When compiling it with JIT compilation it works with no problems. However, now I would like to turn my application to production mode, so I tried AOT compilation. When I try to compile my application with the Angular compiler, as it is shown here: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler. The message shown is the following:

```
Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'FileUploaderModule in /node_modules/@uniprank/ngx-file-uploader/typings/index.d.ts'
```

I am completely lost at this point. Although I have been looking around in the web, I cannot figure out what means that message and how to fix it.

Any ideas to solve this problem will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Probably have to report it to the library maintainers...

Comment: I did it, but as I had no answer from the maintainers, I tried to fix this bug on my own. I forked the repository and tried to deal with it, hoping to do a pull request when I finish, but with no success yet :(

Comment: I went to look at the repo, and the one listed on the package's NPM page doesn't exist. 

Frankly, I'd give up on this library and go find another one. There are a bunch of file uploader components out there - go find one that's actually tested and supported, like maybe http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload

Comment: I am using now the file uploader component that you have suggested and it works like a charm! Thank you so much for your advice.